# How do I retrieve the text in a table column using Selenium RC?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
<table class="theClass">
<tr>
   <td class="anotherClass"><strong>Label1:</strong></td>
   <td colspan="3">Value1a<br/>Value1b<br/>Value1c</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td class="anotherClass"><strong>Label2:</strong></td>
   <td colspan="3">Value2a<br/>Value2b<br/>Value2c</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td class="anotherClass"><strong>Label3:</strong></td>
   <td colspan="3">Value3a<br/>Value3b<br/>Value3c</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I use Selenium RC to retrieve Value1a, Value1b, and Value1c ?  Can I use selenium.getText(...) or storeText(...)?  If so, what is the proper xpath I should use?  Please assume that the table cannot be changed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String value1 = selenium.getText("//tr[1]/td[1]/strong[contains(text(), Label1:')]/../../td[2]");
```

Answer (score 6):

it would  be

```
string value1 = selenium.getTable("table.1.2");
string value2 = selenium.getTable("table.2.2");
```

and so on.

The help text for getTable is

> getTable(tableCellAddress) Arguments:
>
> - tableCellAddress - a cell
>     address, e.g. "foo.1.4"
>
>   Returns:
>         the text from the specified cell
>
>   Gets the text from a cell of a table. The cellAddress syntax
>     tableLocator.row.column, where row and
>     column start at 0.

Comment: Hi, you seem to know a lot about this. What if I have multiple tables? I assume you would just substitute "table" for the id of the table?

Answer (score 3):

Check this,

```
            int i =1;

       while(selenium.isElementPresent("//table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[2]")){
           System.out.println(selenium.getText("//table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td[2]"));
           i++;
       }
```

Result will contain all the values listed.Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

selenium.gettable(xpath)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your first answer! Please elaborate a bit on your answer, try to explain the code you just posted. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer